# Does SVM has an internal feature selection?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, svm

As far as I know, classifiers like SVM or Nuerel Networks try to use all supplied features but Trees make a feature selection internally. Is it possible to make feature selection for SVM internally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a feature selection mechanism in the classic formulation of SVM, but that doesn't mean it can't be done, there have been some attempts:

http://www.andrew.cmu.edu/user/minhhoan/papers/SVMFeatureWeight_PR.pdf

http://ftp.cs.wisc.edu/pub/dmi/tech-reports/02-03.pdf

Comment: Very often, though, regularization (L1 or L2) suffices. Would you agree?

Comment: @ChthonicProject I agree although if you want to use a non-linear kernel you would need something else.